# assignning constructor function to a variable. - why doesn't this code work, using firefox console

Tags: javascript

By assigning the constructor function to a variable, I can't instantiate the object using the function itself. Whynot ?

This works :

```js
function Car() {
  this.j = 'j'
}
var car = new Car();
```

This doesn't work :

```js
var io = function Car() {
  this.j = 'j'
}
var car = new Car();
```

Comment: I get "ReferenceError: Car is not defined"

Comment: This question needs more upvotes....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how it works. You're declaring `io` to the function reference *directly*. So, there's no `Car` function outside the scope of the function body itself.

You can access `Car` inside the function body, for instance, for may be, recursive algorithms.

Javascript allows you to name the function because you may need it(recursion, duh) but only `io` containing the reference of the function exists.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you do:

```
var io = function Car() { ... }
```

For all browsers they will think that the function name is `io` since it declared as so, and as such the function `Car()` is only in the scope of `io`, while others (IE 8 and lower) may work for both `Car` and `io`, and as such I mean two separate objects are created. For the most part there isn't a problem using them. Although because of the IE thing it's better to do either:

```
var io = function() {
    ...
}
var car = new io();
```

Or

```
function Car() {
    ...
}
var car = new Car();
```

I also personally think they are more readable and obvious.

Comment: There is a clearly defined behavior for named function expression. It's true that IE had some problems with NFEs, but they work as expected in all other browsers.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm aware, I'm explaining intuitively why some browsers will work for both `Car` and `io` in this case even though `io` is our reference. But yes, I mainly don't recommend NFEs because of the issue with IE.

Comment: OK. In that case, would you mind describing the issue better? It's not that the function is either available as io or Car. In all browsers it will be available as io, but IE 8 and below will also create a function Car. Your description makes it sound worse than it is ;)

Answer (score -1):

the function name is the name of the variable

```
var io = function () {
  this.j = 'j'
}
var car = new io();
```

other

```
var io = function () {
  this.j = 'j'
  return this
}
var car = io();
```